# Deserializing primitive Gson Keys as primitives

Tags: gson

For the following code

```
public class GsonTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SortedMap<Long, Number> map = new TreeMap<>();
        map.put(System.currentTimeMillis(), 200l);
        String json2 = gson.toJson(map);
        System.out.println(json2);
    }
}
```

I get the following output

```
{"1484140989691":200}
```

Is it possible that primitive keys are not deserialized as Strings and that I could have the following output?

```
{1484140989691:200}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{1484140989691:200}
```

Is not valid JSON.

[Reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6)

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
> from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
> name.  The names within an object SHOULD be unique.
>
> ```
>   object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ]
>            end-object
>
>   member = string name-separator value
> ```